How do I register an app in the options bar when copying text? (Android native)
I'm using dotnet maui but I'm having no success implementing a feature. The feature in question is the following:
1-When selecting a text, Android natively shows a series of available options, such as copy, share, and the Google Translate app. Is there any way to register my app to be shown on this screen?
I'm creating a notepad app, and it would be really interesting if it was already integrated with the clipboard in this way.
